# Matching sets consisting of letters plus non-letter characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match sets of characters that include a letter and non-letter characters. Many of them are a single letter. Or two letters.

```js
const match = 'tɕ\'i mɑ mɑ ku ʂ ɪɛ'.match(/\b(p|p\'|m|f|t|t\'|n|l|k|k\'|h|tɕ|tɕ\'|ɕ|tʂ|tʂ\'|ʂ|ʐ|ts|ts\'|s)\b/g)
console.log(match)
```

I thought I could use `\b`, but it's wrong because there are "non-words" characters in the sets.

This is the current output:

```
[
  "t",
  "m",
  "m"
]
```

But I want this to be the output:

```
[
  "tɕ'",
  "m",
  "m",
  "k",
  "ʂ"
]
```

Note: notice that some sets end with a non-word boundary, like `tɕ'`.

(In phonetic terms, the consonants.)

Comment: `\b` won't work with unicode characters

Comment: Knowing what data you expect would help with creating a proper regex, but going by what we have so far you could try `[^\d\s\\']+`

Comment: 1) Reorganize the alternatives to only require word boundaries where they are necessary or use adaptive word boundaries (e.g. `/\b(?:[pmftnlkhɕʂʐs]|t(?:[ɕʂ]|s))\b|\b(?:[pkt]|t[ʂsɕ])'/g` is an example) 2) decide if you can just use whitespace boundary (i.e. e.g. `/\b(?:[pmftnlkhɕʂʐs]|t(?:[ɕʂ]|s))(?!\S)|\b(?:[pkt]|t[ʂsɕ])'/g`), or you need to implement fully Unicode aware word boundaries.

Comment: "Word" bondaries is a very confusing topic as developers are not unanimous about what to consider a word. So, please explain what "word" boundaries you want to use here.

Comment: You also need to decide if you need to require a "word" boundary if the adjoining impacted char is a non-word char. Please edit the question to clarify all this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Will my Note suffice?

Comment: No, your intent is not clear. You can cut the Gordian knot with the below answer, or precise the requirements.

Comment: It can also help to clarify with a few more examples that include some of the most difficult situations. Your current example is quite simple. For example there are no two consecutive consonants. Also you write "a letter and non-letter characters", but this seems not to be the rule, as "ts" seems to describe one consonant, yet has two letters, ...etc.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for spotting that. I added it.

Comment: What about a more complex example with double consonants, absence of spaces when they are optional, other phonetics that are special, [see for instance this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#/media/File:IPA_chart_2020.svg), ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments above `\b` doesn't with unicode characters in JS and moreover from your expected output it appears that you don't need word boundaries.

You can use this shortened and refactored regex:

```bash
t[ɕʂs]'?|[tkp]'?|[tmfnlhshɕʐʂ]
```

**Code:**

```js
const s = 'tɕ\'i mɑ mɑ ku ʂ ɪɛ';
const re = /t[ɕʂs]'?|[tkp]'?|[tmfnlhshɕʐʂ]/g

console.log(s.match(re))

//=> ["tɕ'", "m", "m", "k", "ʂ" ]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9nVGT/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `t[ɕʂs]'?`: Match `t` followed by any letter inside `[...]` and then an optional `'`

- `|`: OR
- `[tkp]'?`: Match letters `t` or `k` or `p` and then an optional `'`
- `|`: OR
- `[tmfnlhshɕʐʂ])`: Match any letter inside `[...]`